# Change a variable depending on value of url parameter

Tags: php, variables, url-parameters

Is there a php way to change php variables depending on values of certain parameters in a url?

For example, I have this particular url :

```
http://example.com/post-url-that-contains-value2/?custom_parameter=value1-value2-value3
```

What I want to do is to check if value 2 (text string) exits only in custom_parameter without checking in the post url (which unfortunately contains the same string as value 2). And when I check and find value 2 in the custom_parameter, then change $myphpvariable to a specific value.

What I was doing is to do this:

```
$checkurl = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if(preg_match('/^(?=.*custom_parameter)(?=.*value2).*$/m', $checkurl) === 1) {
     $myphpvariable = 'Found!';
     }

else {
     $myphpvariable = 'NOT Found!';
     }
```

Unfortunately, this method checks the entire url and it will change the `$myphpvariable` to `'Found!'` even in the case when the URL is `http://example.com/post-url-that-contains-value2/?custom_parameter=value3` for example.... because it sees value2 in the post url.

Any ideas how to make this work correctly?

Comment: You can use the prameter directly using $Get['pramtername']
Then make strpos on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the uri and parameters separately

```
//explode the url on the ? and get the first part, the uri
$uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0];

//get everything in custom_parameter
$customParameter = $_GET['custom_parameter'];

//check value2 is in not in the uri and is in the params
if(strpos($uri, 'value2') === false && strpos($customParameter, 'value2') !== false){
    $myphpvariable = 'Found!';

}
else {
    $myphpvariable = 'NOT Found!';
}
```

or if you simply want to check custom_parameter and ignore the url

```
//get everything in custom_parameter
$customParameter = $_GET['custom_parameter'];

if(strpos($customParameter, 'value2') !== false){
    $myphpvariable = 'Found!';

}
else {
    $myphpvariable = 'NOT Found!';
}
```

Comment: This sounds great. I tested it but turned out that Wordpress doesn't recognize the custom url parameters :/

Comment: It turned out that your solution works. It was a misconfiguration in my nginx configuration file. I was missing /index.php?q=$uri&$args; Thanks!

Comment: @MartinPatzekov Glad it is sorted :D

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking at the entire url, I would just use the `$_GET` array as it is the easiest way to access the query string parameters by themselves.

`strpos()` is probably the quickest and easiest way using the `$_GET` array to search for specific text, but you could also use a similar approach given that your values are all separated by the same delimiter. This way it will split the `custom_parameter` value string up on the `-` char into an array and then search that array for `value2`.  This could be more useful if you want to search for other values later on.

```
$customParamater = $_GET["custom_parameter"];
$values = explode("-",$customParamater);
if (in_array("value2",$values)) {
     $myphpvariable = 'Found!';
} else {
     $myphpvariable = 'NOT Found!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great idea. I tested it but it turns out that Wordpress doesn't recognize the custom url parameters.

Comment: It turned out that your solution works. It was a misconfiguration in my nginx configuration file. I was missing /index.php?q=$uri&$args; Thanks!